# Google apps settings: MX Records and Cloudflare

Tags: cloudflare, mx-record

We are using CloudFlare for our site.
On the last 3-4 days, I am having issues with Google Apps - suddenly it stopped working.
I saw that other people have the same issues just on the last few days and wanted to get some help because I can't find a solution.

Can you please advice?

Domain is 101greatgoalsdotcom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have CNAME at the root (this technically breaks RFC compliance). Are you able to change your CNAME root to an A record pointing to an IP in your CloudFlare DNS settings? This would solve the issue in the interim. You should also [contact us](http://support.cloudflare.com/cgi/discussion/new) because we have seen a few cases with Google Apps email recently.

Comment: I had the same issue MX record didn't show up after I added , I have www CNAME point to my domain root `example.com` does it the source of the issue .

Comment: OK I solve it by removing CNAME record and MX are show immediately

Answer (score 0):

Your title is misleading, "MX" should say "DNS"

I checked your DNS Records:

```
- You need an "A" for 101greatgoals.com to point to 208.93.139.140
- Your CNAME "www.101greatgoals.com" should point to "101greatgoals.com"
```